# LED ceiling light flashes when another light is turned on

Tags: electrical, dimmer-switch, engineering

I have a circuit with 3 Leviton smart dimmer switches that control 3 different LED ceiling lights, 1 on/off bathroom fan, and 1 on/off LED light. Whenever the 1 on/off LED light is turned on, 1 and only 1 of the dimmer-controlled LED ceiling lights flashes. It's a sputnik-style ceiling light with 12 dimmable LED bulbs in it. The other 2 ceiling lights never flash. The LED bulbs will probably not last as long because of this, but it's damn annoying because it's in our bedroom.

I did some Googling and came up with something called "neutral interaction." Could that be what's happening here? I can't get to these lights' wiring in any way except for at the base, so I can't run another neutral. They're on vaulted, angled ceilings with no attic above them. Is there any way to stop this? Could I put something (diode?, resistor?, filter choke?, ferrite ring?, Lamp Debuzzing Coils (LDCs)?, magic beans?) on the neutral line to this light to stop this?

Comment: do all 12 bulbs flash, or just one? Do they flash continually or just when the on/off changes?

Comment: All 12 bulbs flash very quickly just once.

Comment: That's a lot of bulbs. I would try a different/better dimmer and/or lower wattage LED bulbs. I've had good multi-bulb luck with old-school dimmers and the right LED bulbs; the older dimmer probably has a beefier snubber network on the dimmer. You could also try adding a snubber network across the existing dimmer, there's commercial modules if you don't want to hand-roll one.

Comment: Is a "snubber network" the same thing as a shunt capacitor / MLC?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snubber

Answer (score 0):

I’m not saying this is what is happening with yours, but I had 4 dimmable LED ceiling lights (the flood style lightbulbs) that started strobing every few seconds a few months after I put in a dimmer switch. I swapped out the dimmer switch thinking it was bad, but the problem continued. So I swapped the four builder-installed lightbulbs for four new LED dimmable bulbs and the problem stopped.

Comment: Thanks, but I've tried 3 different dimmable LED bulb brands. All seem to flash the same.